# Failed to open my port for upload purpose \ UTorrent

Tags: port, port-forwarding, upload, utorrent

when doing the download\upload test in UTorrent program it claims my port is not open (Default 17690).

After I plugged my machine directly to the modem (suspect of port forwarding not working), after removing the antivirus I have, and after adding to my firewall inbounds rule regarding to that port, I still fail on the test.

I tried different port (49152).
when doing in CMD the command  netstat -a -n I get for this port two lines:

TCP 0.0.0.0:49152         0.0.0.0              Listening

UDP  [::]:49152            *:*

Can you suggest what should be my next examination tests? is there a good application that for a given port can detect which component blocking it?

Comment: What is your public IP address? Is it a real public address or does your ISP have you behind a NAT?

Comment: How can I verify that?

Comment: When connected to the modem run "ipconfig -all" in a command prompt. If your IP still starts with 10.something or 192.168.something your still behind NAT.

Answer (score 0):

Torrent may be using upnp to tell the router to open the port.  Is your router set up to allow this?  You may have to enable upnp on the router or forward the port manually

Comment: actually I'm not sure this is a router issue, since I plugged my machine to the modem directly. once it will work I'll put the router back to the picture...